# Interested in the history of the Washington Data Processing Center

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in the Washington Data Processing Center that was opened on April 1, 1966.

My questions are:

1. What year did it close?
2. What was the street address of the center?
3. Are there any early photos of the building that housed it?

Comment: Could you please post a new question on this site that focuses on only the pictures of the building? Pictures requests are on-topic, unlike the two first bullets. The two first bullets of the question (What year did it close? What was the street address of the center?) might be better received at http://history.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The Washington Data Processing Center was located in the basement and subbasement of the second wing of the South Building of the USDA between 12th and 14th streets along Independence Avenue, SW, Washington, DC.

The USDA South building was built in stages between 1930-1936 using the designs of Architect Louis A. Simon.